# ClassNotFoundException - Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException when I try to run my web application. I know this is a common error. I've been going through similar questions on StackOverflow but haven't been able to correct the error.

**web.xml**

```
 <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.UserServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UserServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<form method="post" action="UserServlet">
```

[image: Directory Structure]

**Stack trace**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servlets.UserServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:512)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1050)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[image: File structure]

**file structure**

Comment: How are you deploying the code to Tomcat?

Comment: Sometimes on creating of filters or servlets, the class file is not generated in build folder in eclipse.Clean the application and build it once, a .class file is generated in that above said path. This removes class not found error in some cases.

Comment: Provide the project files/folders structure tree.

Comment: @Andreas Right clicking the file Login.jsp file and running on server. If that's what you are asking.

Comment: @FadySaad I did clean the project. But there's no .class file still.

Comment: @VasileBors Already attached it as an image.

Comment: It is a project structure not files structure. (your IDE show folders as packages and some extra informations)

Comment: @VasileBors Added it.

Comment: @FadySaad Please check the file structure. Seems like .class files are being generated.

Comment: Check your deployment assembly if nothing is missing. Properties  > Deployment Assembly

Comment: I cleaned it again. And it works now. I have no idea why it didn't work the first time. Thank you @FadySaad